# MsiDatabaseOpenView returns 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE)

Tags: windows-installer, installscript, installscript-msi

I have a Basic MSI project in InstallShield 2013.  I am trying to dynamically insert items in a combobox using an InstallScript custom action.  I am currently stuck well before actually inserting the items.

When I try to open the view I get ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE.  I would appreciate any advice on what I am missing.

```cpp
function func(hMSI)
   HWND hDatabase;
   HWND hViewlist;
begin
   hDatabase = MsiGetActiveDatabase(hMSI);
   MsiDatabaseOpenView(hDatabase, "SELECT * FROM `ComboBox` WHERE `Property`='PROP'", hViewList);
end;
```

MsiDatabaseOpenView keeps returning 6 (ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) when I use either hDatabase or hMSI as the first parameter.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I just hit this today and I'm starting to look into it.

Comment: This is working in IS2012 Spring.  I don't have IS2013 to test.